# Finding a break in continuous indices in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have a conditional statement for an array A(assume it is A>10) and I get the following boolean result.

```
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False])
```

Now I am finding the indices where the values are True. I get the following array.

```
array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,
       37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 60, 61, 62, 63,
       64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
       81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90])
```

What I need to do is to find the start index and end index of continuous indices. For example, in the above array the start index of the first of the continuous indices is 20 and the end index is 49. Similarly, the start index of the second set of continuous indices is 60 and the end index is 90.

So to summarize, my output should be :

```
start_indices = array([20,60])

end_indices = array([49,90])
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

# With A as the original array
changes = np.where(np.diff(A > 10))[0] # Gets the actual array out of a tuple
start = changes[::2] + 1
end = changes[1::2]
```

Comment: What have you considered as 'A' here? The real array or the final "TRUE" indices?

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify what I was using as `A`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `groupby` and `accumulate` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby, accumulate

## input array
#a = array([False, False, ..., True, ..., False])

indices = list(accumulate(len(list(g)) for i,g in groupby(a)))
starts = indices[:len(indices)//2*2:2]
stops = [i-1 for i in indices[1::2]]
```

*NB. it works with any iterable, not only numpy arrays.*

output:

```
>>> starts
[20, 60]
>>> stops
[49, 90]
```

Comment: I would like to know what have you assumed as 'a' here.

Comment: Sorry, `a` is the array/iterable